# Java LR or LL Parsing

Tags: java, parsing, grammar, language-lawyer

a teacher of mine said, that Java cannot be LL parsed.
I dont understand this and wonder if this is true.

I searched for a grammar of Java 8 and found this: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/Java8.g4

But even if I try to analyze the grammar, I dont get the problem for LL parsing.
Does anyone know if this is true, know a scientific proof or just can explain to me why it should be not possible to find a grammar construct of Java which can be LL parsed?

Thanks a lot guys and girls.

Comment: consider retagging to include "language lawyer" as one of the tags.

Comment: I would distinguish between the LL-parseability of the language and some grammar of the language. Your teacher apparently doesn't. I at least can't think of anything that would affect the LL parseability of Java (though I haven't actually seen or written an LL grammar of Java either).

Comment: The following branch allows ANTLR 4 to parse Java 8 using a literal transcription of the grammar in the language specification. Not only does it allow parsing Java 8 with an LL parser, it actually allows it without even altering the grammar to a form traditionally used by LL parser generators, and produces a parse tree which accurately reflects the concrete syntax used in the language specification. https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4/tree/java8-grammar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification for Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) says it is not `LL(1)`:

> The grammar presented in this chapter is the basis for the
>   reference implementation. Note that it is not an LL(1) grammar, though
>   in many cases it minimizes the necessary look ahead.

If you either find:

- left recursion, or
- an alternative `(A|B)` that the intersection of two or more alternatives share the same `FIRST` set; `FIRST(A)` has one or more symbols also in `FIRST(B)`

Your grammar won't be `LL(1)`.

Comment: And if a grammar is not LL(1) it is also not possible that the grammar is LL(n) for n >= 0? Am I right with that?

Comment: @Benny You are not correct. If a grammar is not LL(*k*), then it is also not LL(*a*) for any *a* < *k*.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to the left recursion. LL parsers cannot handle left recursion and the current Java grammar is specified in some cases using them, at least Java 7.

Of course, it is well known that one can construct equivalent grammars getting rid of left recursions, but in its current specification Java language could not be LL parsed.